# match all if the user doesn't specify the field value MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building an API where I have several fields that are optional in my get request. So I want MongoDB to match all values for those optional fields if the user does not specify it. I have come up with this solution:

```
db.collection(expenses_collection).find(username: username, category: {$regex:"/" + category + "/"}, payment_type: {$regex:"/" + payment_type + "/"}})
```

Where if category and payment_type are not specified by the user I set them to ".*":

`const {category=".*", payment_type=".*"} = req.query;`

However, mongodb is still not matching any data. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this is quiet confusing !! From `username: username` isn't that `username` is unique ? It will get you all docs where username matches with input ! Then what is the purpose of `category` & `payment_type` ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your regex string. To match any string value, you have to use this pattern (this matches any string): `(.*?)`

Consider input documents:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "John", category: "cat 1", payment_type: "cash" },
{ _id: 2, name: "Jane", category: "cat 2", payment_type: "credit card" }
```

Usage to match any `category` field value:

```
let categoryStr = /(.*?)/
db.exp.find( { category: categoryStr } )
```

The query returns all documents.

So, in your application for the `category` value not specified the code can be like this:

```
if (category is empty or null) { // category  not specified by user
   categoryStr = /(.*?)/
}
```

Similarly, for the `payment_type` field also.

Then query would be:

```
db.exp.find( { 
  username: usernameStr, 
  category: categoryStr,  
  payment_type: paymentStr
} )
```

NOTE: The code tests fine with MongoDB NodeJS driver APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what [exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) is made for?

```
{category: { $exists: true }, payment_type: { $exists: true }}
```

Comment: exists works but I don't want to write multiple queries for the same purpose like if category is chosen by the user and payment_type is not and vice versa. In the case of exists I will have to write queries like:
{category: { $exists: true }, payment_type: { $exists: true }}\n
{category: category, payment_type: { $exists: true }}\n
{category: { $exists: true }, payment_type: payment_type\n
{category: category, payment_type:  payment_type}

Depending on the given fields by the user